# Is any way to rotate UIButton Image without Button Rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I just want to rotate button image without rotating the button. My code is:

```
self.toggle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
self.toggle.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/4)
```